# Python: Button widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have just now begun with GUI programming in Python 2.7 with Tkinter.

I want to have a button **Browse**, which when clicked opens the Windows File Explorer and returns the path of file selected to a variable. I wish to use that path later.

I am following the code given [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog). It outputs a window displaying 5 buttons, but the buttons do nothing. On clicking the first button, it doesn't open the selected file.

Likewise, on clicking the second button, the `askopenfilename(self)` function  is called and it should return a filename. Like I mentioned, I need that filename later.

How to I get the value returned by the function into some variable for future use?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in using `return` inside a callback to a button. It won't return to anywhere. The way to make a callback save data is to store it in a global variable, or an instance variable if you use classes.

```
def fetchpath():
    global filename
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = 'E:')
```

FWIW (and unrelated to the question): you're making a very common mistake. In python, when you do `foo=bar().baz()`, `foo` takes the value in `baz()`. Thus, when you do this:

```
button = Button(...).pack()
```

`button` will take the value of `pack()` which always returns `None`. You should separate widget creation from widget layout if you expect to save an actual reference to the widget being created. Even if you're not, it's a good practice to separate the two.

Comment: I corrected the `pack` mistake. I am still not able to use `global filename`  `NameError: global name 'filename' is not defined`

Comment: @Nancy: You must have other bugs in your program. You shouldn't get that error, but without seeing the code I can't even guess.

Comment: My mistake.Got it figured out now.